# Hook on google chrome pydbg

Tags: python, windows

I am learning to use pyDbg and im set a soft hook on firefox

Part of the code

```
dbg = pydbg()
hooks = utils.hook_container()


for (pid,name) in dbg.enumerate_processes():
    if name == "firefox.exe":
        dbg.attach(pid)

hook_address = dbg.func_resolve_debuggee("nspr4.dll","PR_Write")

hooks.add( dbg, hook_address, 2, sniff, None )

dbg.run()
```

Now how do I set soft hook on google chrome ?

Sorry for bad English and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do it exactly the same way, except that the function names will differ and that you will want to attach to the process whose name matches your Chrome instance.

Alternatively you can use the `load()` function of `pydbg` to start a Chrome instance yourself and debug that. In this case you will also need to handle the `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` in order to be able to set the break point after the DLL got loaded. See below.

The crux is that you will need debug symbols (on Windows those are the `.pdb` files) matching your Chrome build. This is likely what's missing in your scenario.

```
import sys
try:
    from pydbg import *
    from pydbg.defines import *
    from utils import hooking
except:
    print "ERROR: you need pydbg and utils.hooking from PAIMEI."
    sys.exit(-1)

hooks = None # needed in handler_load_dll()

def entry_SomeChromeFunction(dbg, args):
    """ This is where you end up when the function got called """
    # Do whatever you like in here
    return DBG_CONTINUE

def handler_load_dll(dbg):
    last_dll = dbg.get_system_dll(-1)
    # Wait for the DLL we're looking for ...
    if "some-chrome.dll".lower() == last_dll.name.lower():
        # Now resolve the address of the function (see note: requires debug symbols)
        funcaddr = dbg.func_resolve(last_dll.name,"SomeChromeFunction")
        # Add the hook
        hooks.add(dbg, funcaddr, 2, entry_SomeChromeFunction, None) # <- last one is for breakpoint on exit of the function
    return DBG_CONTINUE

dbg = pydbg()
hooks = utils.hook_container()
dbg.load("chrome.exe"); # assuming that is the name of the binary
# you can also use a full path above and pass the command line as parameter
dbg.set_callback(LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT, handler_load_dll)
dbg.run()
```

**Note:** I think it should be possible to assign the address of the function directly without calling `func_resolve_debuggee()`. But I never needed to do that.

**Also note:** my initial code had a bug. `dbg.func_resolve_debuggee()` should not be used in the LOAD_DLL handler, this is corrected now.

**Edit:** I see that your original sample is quite literally a stripped down version of `firefox_hook.py` from [Gray Hat Python](http://nostarch.com/ghpython.htm). The sample is rather good, but it assumes that you *know* what you do - including having the debug symbols in place.